# appendBezierPathWithGlyph fails in [NSBezierPath currentPoint]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Has anybody an idea in which case this can happen?

GDB output:

```
0 .. 8:  kill, abort, objc_exception_throw etc.
9:  0x00007fff87ea21f4 in +[NSException raise:format:] ()
10: 0x00007fff8694e9e2 in -[NSBezierPath currentPoint] ()
11: 0x00007fff869e3b3b in __NSAppendBezierPathWithGlyphs ()
12: 0x00007fff869e5baf in -[NSBezierPath appendBezierPathWithGlyphs:count:inFont:]()
13: 0x00007fff869e2e2d in -[NSBezierPath appendBezierPathWithGlyph:inFont:] ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objc_exception_throw` is the function to throw an exception. There are two things to look at in this circumstance: The Console log, which will identify the exception itself, and the call stack leading to `objc_exception_throw`.

In this case, I can guess what the exception was from the call stack alone: `currentPoint` will throw if the path has no current point. This is backed up by [the documentation for the `appendBezierPathWithGlyphs:count:inFont:` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/appendBezierPathWithGlyphs:count:inFont:) (as well as [for the method you're directly calling](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/appendBezierPathWithGlyph:inFont:)):

> You must set the path's current point (using the `moveToPoint:` method or through the creation of a preceding line or curve segment) before you invoke this method.